# ajax object sending to controller not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I just wanted to send list of Id numbers which collected from checkbox values. Following example code i already tried but not working mvc controller doesn't grab any Id values. Please check code bellow and tell me whats wrong i am doing here.

```js
var _groupids = [];
$('input[class="groupids"]:checked').each(function() {
  _groupids.push(this.value);
});

var ticks = {};
$.each(_groupids, function(key, value) {
  ticks['Id'] = value;
});
console.log(ticks);

$.post('/MyController/Create', {
  groupIds: JSON.stringify(ticks)
}).done(function(data) {

});
```

Model:

```csharp
namespace Demo.ViewModels
{
  public class Ppp
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Controller:

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(List<Ppp> data)
{
  //want to get ajax value in `data`
}
```

Note: I also tried removing `JSON.stringify` but still not receives any value in controller

I also tried to sending this value like this `ticks = '[{"Id": 1}, {"Id": 2}, {"Id": 3}]';` and still not receives any value in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many issues here:

1. `ticks['Id'] = value` uses the same key at each iteration. You are effectively overriding the value from the previous iteration.
2. However that wouldn't help, because you need to post a list, and you are posting an object that looks something like this: `{"Id": 4}`. That's not a list by any measure.
3. You call parameter `groupIds` in js, while controller expects `data`.

So you need to make sure your parameter names match, and the data that you send should be looking like that:

```
[{"Id": 1}, {"Id": 2}, {"Id": 3}]
```

You can do that if `ticks` was an array, and got inserted a new object on each iteration.

Comment: and `this.value` does not return `id` of element

Comment: @demo, thanks, this also. Although I suspect author actually wants values and not id

Comment: Ok. Good answer. But can u tell me even if i send your provided value to controller still not receives any ids. Like `ticks = '[{"Id": 1}, {"Id": 2}, {"Id": 3}]'`

Comment: @johnHuo, please update your question with how do you send it

Comment: @johnHuo, that's not what I meant though. "How" means how are you using this new ticks value. Say if you still post it as `groupIds` without renaming the controller's parameter, that still wont' work

Comment: And @demo this.value returning the value of checkbox which is id. So it is good to use this.value. Its returning me the ids already